# Data binding with angularjs-google-map

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, data-binding

I want to use data-binding to insert the coordinates into Google maps to angular. 
The data are well binds but nothing appears

```
<div class ="ng-scope" ng-repeat ="v in toto" ng-model = "v">
            <google-map center="{latitude:'{{v.farmlatitude}}',longitude:'{{v.farmlongitude}}'}" zoom="18" draggable="true" refresh="true" ></google-map>
                </div>
```

i have look in the inspector element :

```
<google-map center="{latitude:'49.918757',longitude:'8.171847'}" zoom="18" draggable="true" refresh="true"></google-map>
```

So when i have replaced the data-binding with numbers, its ok.

Can you help me please

Comment: please create plunker and provide the link

Comment: Hi @alexandreecormier .. Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

## 2 posibilities:

- script/link tags in your index.html
- is there a css file with .angular-google-map class defined ?

Comment: Yes it's ok.... When I declare in the scope all is ok, and when I want do data binding, its doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my problem. You may write :

```
<google-map center="{latitude: farm.farmlatitude, longitude:farm.farmlongitude}" zoom="17" draggable="true" refresh="true" ></google-map>
```